# Aptana studio doesn't recognize ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, aptana3

[image: Error complaint from Aptana Studio 3]

I get this error on ruby syntax after installing the Aptana Eclipse plugin. I think I might have failed an install, because I did get an error after I opened up Eclipse a while ago. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bad install. I was missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Aptana RadRails in order to develope with Ruby on Rails. It is a free IDE. Or you should try RubyMines by JetMinds that is the one I used.

Hope this answers your question